# What is the best way to update form controls from a worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I've done some research and I can't really find a preferred way to do updating of form controls from a worker thread in C#.  I know about the BackgroundWorker component, but what is the best way to do it without using the BackgroundWorker component?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a general rule of thumb that says don't update the UI from any thread other than the UI thread itself. Using the features of the BackgroundWorker is a good idea, but you don't want to and something is happening on a different thread, you should do an "Invoke" or BeginInvoke to force the delegate to execute the method on the UI thread.

Edit: Jon B made this good point in the comments:

> Keep in mind that Invoke() is
>   synchronous and BeginInvoke() is
>   asynchronous. If you use Invoke(), you
>   have to be careful not to cause a
>   deadlock. I would recommend
>   BeginInvoke() unless you really need
>   the call to be synchronous.

Some simple example code:

```
// Updates the textbox text.
private void UpdateText(string text)
{
  // Set the textbox text.
  m_TextBox.Text = text;
}

public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string text);

// Then from your thread you can call this...
m_TextBox.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText),
    new object[]{"Text generated on non-UI thread."});
```

The code above is from a FAQ about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx) and a longer more involved one [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/articles/126345.aspx).

Comment: What exactly does the m_TextBox.Invoke do?  Does it force the delegate to be executed on the UI thread?

Comment: Exactly. Keep in mind that Invoke() is synchronous and BeginInvoke() is asynchronous. If you use Invoke(), you have to be careful not to cause a deadlock. I would recommend BeginInvoke() unless you really need the call to be synchronous.

Comment: Good call, Jon B. I should have mentioned that. I'll edit to reflect the point.

Comment: So what is the benefit of using this method as opposed to a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I wouldn't say that there was necessarily a benefit to using this approach over the BackgroundWorker but the question specifically said "...but what is the best way to do it without using the BackgroundWorker component?" :)

Comment: I see, I guess I thought maybe there was a known issue that I have not seen using the BackgroundWorker that Yttrium found during his research

Comment: How could the use of Invoke cause a deadlock?

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you want to do it using the BackgroundWorker? It has a fantastic callback event called ProgressChanged which lets the UI thread know about updates, perfect for progess bar-type updates and the like.

[link to details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a discussion related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184/how-do-i-make-event-callbacks-into-my-win-forms-thread-safe#6189) and one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120540/how-to-update-components-in-different-threads-net-cf).

Essentially, you use Invoke to accomplish it.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider InvokeRequired (VS2008 only) when calling Invoke.  There are times that you will not be updating the UI from a seperate thread.  It saves the overhead of creating the delegate etc.

```
if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            //This.Invoke added to circumvent cross threading exceptions.
            this.Invoke(new UpdateProgressBarHandler(UpdateProgressBar), new object[] { progressPercentage });
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateProgressBar(progressPercentage);
        }
```